# Iphone UITextField take integer

Tags: iphone

```
int integer = [myUITexrtField.text intValue];
```

I know this thing with this we can get the int value from the textField
But i want to give a integer value to the textField.
I am using this.

```
int i=10;
[myUITexrtField.text intValue]=i;
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `myUITexrtField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];`

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert the int to a string:

```
myUITexrtField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
```

Comment: but when i am printing the myUITexrtField.text, i am getting (null).

Answer (score -1):

Use the `setIntValue` method.

```
[myUITextField setIntValue: i];
```

Comment: setIntValue mathod not shoing